# bring back context menu column formatter/field cutomizer

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I noticed, as soon as I apply any sort of formatting to SharePoint existing columns it looses its context menu.

I tried the column formatter JSON as well as field customizer.

Is there a way we can keep the context menu as it is and do our formatting or if we have any JSON/or anything in field customizer extension, to bring back the context menu?

Comment: What is the JSON code you are using for formatting? Can you please add any screenshot or anything for more clarification?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, use any JSON for example {
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField"
}, using it on document lib name column

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online JSON formatting now supports opening context menu easily by using `openContextMenu` action under `customRowAction` property.

**For example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "openContextMenu"
  },
  "style": {
    "color": "green"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**: It shows context menu on click of formatted column.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON Formatting syntax reference - customRowAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#customrowaction)